# What's the difference between the "Win-D" and "Win-M" shortcuts?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I was wondering in what situation will we see a difference between <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> ?

[This thread](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/163720-wind-vs-winm/) claims that the former does a "show desktop" while the latter does a "minimize all" (but of course there's no difference between those two),

Whereas [this thread](http://osdir.com/ml/windows.off-topic/2003-05/msg01214.html) talks about stuff like wm_minimize message..

Now I was wondering what's the real difference between them?

Why have two shortcuts that do the same thing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"Minimize All" - <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, that is - sends a minimize command to all windows. However, some windows don't support the minimize command, and will thus still be visible.

In those cases, <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, "Show Desktop", will get you to the desktop. Note that the windows that don't support minimizing are still there, unminimized - they just become invisible.

Comment: also note that you can press Win+D *again* to restore everything, whereas pressing Win+M again doesn't restore.

Comment: @studiohack what about the WIN+SHIFT+M?

Comment: @Graeme btw do you know which windows are those that don't support minimizing?

Comment: They're not invisible, they're behind the desktop [which is an actual window - the "real" desktop from the 3.1 era isn't normally visible].

Comment: @Pacerier: any window without a minimize button.

Comment: Also Win+D is easier to press with one hand than Win+M

Comment: @studiohack: Re. "also note that you can press Win+D again to restore everything": Not if you've opened any Windows since pressing Win+D, which, btw, imho, makes it pretty useless (unless you just want to see (but not use) the Icons on your Windows Desktop or your Desktop Wallpaper).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. i want to add one more difference between WIN+D and WIN+M. Assume you are currently in some window and If you will use the key WIN+D it will take you to the desktop and then if you will use the same key again you will be taken back to the previous window where you started. But it is not the case with the WIN+M. Once you use the key WIN+M it will minimize all open windows which leaves you the desktop but if you press the same key again you will not be taken to those windows. it is my observation.